# How to paste a password in Remmina when connecting to a remote xrdp server

Tags: 22.04, remote-desktop, xrdp, rdp, remmina

I'm stuck when it comes to paste my password when connecting to a remote machine with RDP (xrdp server) using [Remmina](https://remmina.org/):

[image]

I'm not able to paste my password in the field.

What I've tried (none of these is working):

- Ctrl+V
- Ctrl+Shift+V
- Mouse right click (no contextual menu is showing)
- Mouse middle click

Manually typing it is not an option as it's a very long random string.

Version:

```
$ remmina -v
remmina-Message: 20:40:40.645: Remmina does not log all output statements. Turn on more verbose output by using "G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all" as an environment variable.
More info available on the Remmina wiki at:
https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/wikis/Usage/Remmina-debugging
Load modules from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/remmina/plugins
Remmina plugin glibsecret (type=Secret) has been registered, but is not yet initialized/activated. The initialization order is 2000.
The glibsecret secret plugin has been initialized and it will be your default secret plugin
org.remmina.Remmina - 1.4.25 (git n/a)
```

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64
Kernel: 5.15.0-47-generic

Note:
Remmina is apparently expecting a 'qwerty' keyboard layout by default on my system (see also: https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/) and my keyboard is a 'qwertz'. -> Going to: Remmina / Preferences / RDP / and ticking [x] "Use client keyboard mapping" to use your own keyboard layout.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Click on the wrench icon or Tools on the left, then select `Keystrokes`.  Then select `Send clipboard content as keystrokes`

[image]

**EDIT:** Thanks to [@s.k](https://askubuntu.com/users/571173/s-k) there is an issue where Remmina doesn't detect by default the keyboard layout on the remote system.  It is a simple fix.

From Remmina home click on the menu on the right and select Preferences:

[image]

Next select RDP on the left hand side:

[image]

Then select Use Client Keyboard Mapping:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it seems to paste a lot of '*' so I guess this is working, but the server fails establishing the connection with `pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure / Username or password error for user: username` in `/var/log/xrdp-sesman.log`. I'm wondering; is their any length or character set limitation in Remmina?

Comment: @s.k If you have special characters in your password is may do that.  Sometimes you should be putting single quotes `' '` around your passwords so they are literal.

Comment: I've figured it out by pasting the password into the username field: it's a keyboard layout missmatch issue: https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/2279#issuecomment-1135691068 Remmina is apparently expecting a 'qwerty' keyboard layout by default on my system and my keyboard is a 'qwertz'. -> Going to: Remmina / Preferences / RDP / and ticking [x] "Use client keyboard mapping" solved this.

Comment: @s.k Good find!  Glad you solved it!  :)