# Remmina rdp from linux to windows: win key and others not working inside session

Tags: shortcut-keys, windows-10, rdp, remmina

I'm connected with remmina from ubuntu to windows 10 in full screen mode.
If I press WIN it does not display the windows start menu, but the ubuntu activities instead.
It's like, if those keys were not mapped at all in remmina, they keep working as if I was only using linux.

Can I get a fully immersive session, where no matter what key I press, it's handled by windows and not linux?

Comment: You might want to see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434609/how-to-paste-a-password-in-remmina-when-connecting-to-a-remote-xrdp-server/1434614#1434614 and in the second half of the answer on how to set the client keyboard.